# Dependent-type design when the parameters indicate the result should not exist

Tags: matlab, matrix, option-type, coq, dependent-type

This is a follow-up on [my previous question on dependently-typed arbitrarily-dimensioned matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66863226/4400820).

I have defined a matrix type, where each natural in `dims` defines the size of the corresponding dimension. For example, for some type `A`, `matrix A [3; 5; 2]` is a 3x5x2 matrix:

```
Require Import Coq.Unicode.Utf8.
Require Export Vector.
Import VectorNotations.
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint matrix (A: Type) (dims: list nat) :=
  match dims with
  | [] => A
  | head::tail => Vector.t (matrix A tail) head
  end.
```

I have also defined a `get` function that accesses an element of the matrix when all indices are specified:

```
Fixpoint get {A: Type} {dims: list nat} (m: matrix A dims) (indexes: list nat): option A :=
  if Nat.eqb (length dims) (length indexes)
  then match dims, indexes return matrix A dims → option A with
       | [], [] => λ a, Some a
       | dimh::dimt, idxh::idxt => λ m',
           match Fin.of_nat (idxh - 1) dimh with
           | inleft H => @get A dimt (Vector.nth m' H) idxt
           | _ => None
           end
       | _, _ => λ _, None
       end m
  else None.
```

Now I would like to support MATLAB-style indexers, where an index is either a scalar or a range; the special range `:` means "all the corresponding elements in that dimension." This function need not handle MATLAB's ability to only specify some of the indices; we will assume all indices are provided. Some examples:

```matlab
>> A = rand(3,5,2)

A(:,:,1) =

    0.8147    0.9134    0.2785    0.9649    0.9572
    0.9058    0.6324    0.5469    0.1576    0.4854
    0.1270    0.0975    0.9575    0.9706    0.8003


A(:,:,2) =

    0.1419    0.7922    0.0357    0.6787    0.3922
    0.4218    0.9595    0.8491    0.7577    0.6555
    0.9157    0.6557    0.9340    0.7431    0.1712

>> size(A)

ans =

     3     5     2

>> A(1,1,1)

ans =

    0.8147

>> A(1,1,:)       

ans(:,:,1) =

    0.8147


ans(:,:,2) =

    0.1419

>> A(1,2:4,:)

ans(:,:,1) =

    0.9134    0.2785    0.9649


ans(:,:,2) =

    0.7922    0.0357    0.6787
```

I can define the type to represent the indexers:

```
Inductive range: Type :=
  | Scalar: nat → range
  | Subrange: nat → nat → range
  | Fullrange.
```

But where I'm struggling is to compute the resulting type for the function. My initial thought was to define a function `range_dimensions: list nat -> list range -> list nat` with the idea that each scalar in the range list gives a dimension of `1`, each sub-range gives a dimension of the size of the subrange, and each full-range gives a dimension of the corresponding size of the dimensions list (the first parameter).

However, when the lists aren't the same size, or when one part of the subrange is out of bounds (e.g., `Subrange 3 5` for a dimension of size `4`), *there is no good result to return*—in other words, I would prefer to have `range_dimensions: list nat -> list range -> option (list nat)`. But that raises the question of what to do with the actual indexing function:

```
Fixpoint get_range {A: Type} {dims: list nat} (m: matrix A dims) (indexes: list range): matrix A (range_dimensions dims indexes)
```

This won't work, because the types don't line up. What I would really like is to return an `option (matrix A (range_dimensions dims indexes))` that is `None` when the dimensions computation fails and `Some …` otherwise, but I can't see a way to do this. There just is no type to put in for the `option (matrix A …)` when the dimensions-list is `None`:

```
Axiom range_dimensions_ex: option (list nat)
Check match range_dimensions_ex with
      | Some dims => matrix nat dims
      | None => option (matrix nat ???)
      end.
```

I think this means I'm stuck with something I saw in [Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/), which is to use something like

```
Fixpoint get_range {A: Type} {dims: list nat} (m: matrix A dims) (indexes: list range):
match (range_dimensions dims indexes) with
| None => unit
| Some dims' => matrix A dims'
end
```

Which seems very unwieldy to work with, especially given that so far my other matrix functions return `option (matrix A …)` to indicate indexing failure, rather than `tt`.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? Is there a design that more accurately reflects what I'm aiming to do? Note that this is intended to make its way into an expression-evaluation function for a (very small) subset of MATLAB semantics—if I'm stuck with `unit`, how can I otherwise integrate with functions that are returning `option`?

Comment: Have you considered eschewing dependent types? Program with simple types, and reason about dimensions only in proofs. MATLAB just seems inherently very dynamic, whereas dependent types require a strong discipline about the flow of static and dynamic information.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia we’re actually planning to mostly avoid the dynamic conversions that MATLAB does when you have, say, matrix + scalar. Are you suggesting using something like lists of lists? Examples as a frame-challenge would be welcome—wouldn’t the functions need to match on A in list A to determine if A is another list or not (another dimension in the matrix)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One general approach to programming in Coq is to keep dependent types confined to specifications, without using them in programs.

So for instance, a matrix could be represented as a pair of its dimensions and its contents in a nested recursive type

```
Inductive matrix_ :=
| Scalar : scalar -> matrix_
| Matrix : list matrix_ -> matrix_
.

Record matrix :=
  { dim : list nat
  ; contents : matrix_
  }.
```

Then you'd need some predicate to specify when matrices are "well-formed":

```
Definition well_formed : matrix -> Prop := ...
```

Operations would have simple types:

```
Definition submatrix : matrix -> range -> matrix := ...
```

And all the complexity moves into the specs:

```
Theorem submatrix_wf (m : matrix) (r : range)
  : well_formed m -> valid_range m r -> well_formed (submatrix m r).

Theorem submatrix_dim (m : matrix) (r : range)
  : well_formed m -> valid_range m r -> dim (submatrix m r) = dim_range r.

(* etc. *)
```

- It is a simple representation
- On ill-formed inputs, you can simply return garbage without explicit `option` (whereas with more structured representations, there might not even be room for "garbage"); errors will be caught if you verify your program.
- You still get many of the benefits of static typing: can't confuse matrices, scalars, booleans, dimensions...

The main trade-off is that a rich representation using dependent types provides well-formedness proofs for free, but getting the program to typecheck at all can be an arbitrarily difficult task. With a dumb representation you only get the most basic sanity checks from the program itself (still more than actual MATLAB). However, the tediousness of the separate proofs can be alleviated to a great extent by automation.

Comment: How does this tie in to an evaluation function? Eg, I define an inductive type of the syntax of expressions, and an evaluation function that is a recursive match on that type. Do I just throw my submatrix/etc into that? How do I handle errors, eg, when the range is not valid? You say return garbage—but the evaluator has to *know* when it is garbage, no? Or will my proofs about programs need to include properties about well-formedness? I’m having a hard time reasoning through how to connect everything. (Perhaps well-formedness is decidable? So use reflection?)

Comment: (In any case, thank you for this alternative perspective; I’ve got some thinking to do!)

Comment: Yes, you would presumably have a `Submatrix` constructor for `M(x,y,z)`, then you can write `match e with Submatrix me re => submatrix (eval_matrix me) (eval_range re) | ... end`. You can represent errors explicitly by making your functions produce `option`.